# How to set custom DNS entry for a particular wifi connection

Tags: wifi, network, dns

Is there a way to set custom DNS settings for a single wifi connection without affecting other connections?

I use my laptop at home and work. When at work I need to type in an IP address of a local DNS server to resolve company resources. I currently do this by pressing the "Advanced..." button on the network preferences page. Unfortunately this setting is global for all of my wifi connections. So when I go home I need to remove the DNS setting.

Can I set the DNS setting to only work while I'm connected to the company's wifi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want to do is [Add a Network Location](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21634) for work.

You can then easily switch between them using the Location submenu of the  menu.

If you really wanted, you could [set up a script to switch locations based on network](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2005010613401823), but really, how lazy do you want to be? ;)

Comment: I'm lazy! Launchbar speeds DNS changes by location :-) [How can I quickly change DNS servers?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23134/how-can-i-quickly-change-dns-server)

Comment: It's odd as you can only (afaik) set it per-network on iOS.

Comment: This feature is being removed in macOS Ventura, so we might need a new answer… https://www.macrumors.com/2022/08/12/apple-removes-network-locations-macos-ventura/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Control Plane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) to switch context automatically depending on nearby WiFi networks, location, … or tons of other conditions.